# How to properly use a SerializeReference field in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have one class contain a list of scripts that all have the same interface.

Here's the three scripts I'm using currently:

ICollisionScript.cs:

```
public interface ICollisionScript {
    public void OnCollision(BallController ball) {
        
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a skeleton of a script that implements that interface, RandomEffect.cs:

```
public class RandomEffect: ICollisionScript {
    public void OnCollision(BallController ball) {
        // some random effect
    }
}
```

Lastly, in the 'base' script BallController.cs is where I want to see a list of these scripts:

```
[SerializeReference] public List<ICollisionScript> collisionScripts;
```

I see this show up in the Unity inspector; however, if I try to drag the RandomEffect.cs file/script into the list, it simply won't work. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity3d does not support interface serialization in the inspector (at least by default). So you have several options:

- You can derive your scripts from any derived from Unity3d object class (both ScriptableObject and MonoBehaviour will work here depending on your needs). I think MonoBehaviour will fit better in this case.
- You can use Odin inspector. It allows to serialize interfaces in the inspector. However, even considering the fact that this works, I don't recommend this option as it adds unnecessary headaches with code stripping.

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesn't allow you to drag scripts directly to the inspector. You need to apply it to a gameobject that you can then drag into the list.

Unity only executes Update() and other functions from MonoBehaviour when the script is attached to an object. That's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference to script as non-monobehaviour object in Unity you can use [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html)

```
public abstract class CollisionScript : ScriptableObject {
    public abstract void OnCollision(BallController ball);
}


[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "RandomEffect", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/CollisionScript/RandomEffect", order = 1)]
public class RandomEffect: CollisionScript {
    public void OnCollision(BallController ball) {
    // some random effect
    }
}
```